# Unity 2D colliders and rigidbodies

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Unity2D- i have a player with a rigidbody and a collider, and part of the map with a collider as well. I am using the collider to load everything in that part of the map. How would I get the Rigidbody to not collide with the collider on the map, but still send a message to load/unload everything in that part of the map?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. sorry. needed to make the map a trigger, and use OnTriggerEnter()